# Как сделать кнопку Share чтоб поделиться статьей приложения (картинка,заголовок, текст и т.д.)?

Tags: swift, share, tableview, uibutton

Ребята подскажите урок как сделать кнопку , человек зашел посмотреть статью, и хочется с ней поделиться твиттер, фейсбук .Вот пример такая статья. прикрепляю картинку.Не могу разобраться как метод такой называется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller), и вот [туториал](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133825/uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial) на всякий случай

Comment: Спасибо , буду разбираться.